# Apache ranger yarn plugin is not working as expected?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-ranger

I have kerberized hadoop. I install ranger yarn plugin on resourcemanager & data nodes. Then i configure **install.properties** as below:

```
Repository Name       :  yarndev

Description           :  yarn repository

Username              :  yarn

Password              :  {password for yarn user in the system}

YARN REST URL         :  http://rm1:8088;http://rm2:8088
```

I ve created yarn plugin in ranger admin ui as **yarndev**

After I run **enable.sh** and restart both **resourcemanager** and **nodemanager** services.

I ve seen 2 plugin on admin panel. (there 2 plugin is yarn plugin which is on my resourcemanager nodes)

When I update policy the 2 nodes download the policy i can see.

The problem is It doesnt effect anything. I mean any user can submit spark or hive app on any queue what they select.

I want to put restrictions to use queues.

I have `capacity scheduler xml` to configure my que settings and i can see when i enable yarn plugin in `yarn-site.xml` there are 2 parts to added to last of the file like **yarn.acl.enable** to **true** and other thing is **yarn.authorization-provider**

the other thing is when i look on data nodes i can see there is a folder like `/etc/ranger/yarndev/policycache/` but this folder is empty. it s like datanodes never get policy from ranger admin. I dont know why because there is no log under `/var / log /yarn/ nodemanager.log`

So what is the thing that i am missing?

Comment: There should be a toggle switch in the policy screen "Deny All Other Accesses". It should be under "Allow Conditions" section. Is it enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configure my each queue include root in `capacity scheduler xml`

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue-path>.acl_submit_applications` To space **" "**

And

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue-path>.acl_administer_queue` To space and `yarn` **" yarn"** which means that only yarn group submit app in every queue

But i apply above settings with just root without sub queue names like `root.acl_administer_queue`

Thats it , it works like a charm